# jQuery: Changing opacity of an element while scrolling

Tags: transparency, opacity

How do I change the opacity of element mm e.g  Content  while scrolling? I mean, while the page is scrolling, I want my layer to be half-transparent but when I stop scrolling, want it to get back to non-transparent in style.

Comment: What have you tried? Shouldn't just `.scroll()` and `.css({ opacity: xx })` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script worked for me. I wanted to show a message during the first 150pixels, so opacity will run from 1 to 0.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).scroll(function(){
            var top=$(this).scrollTop();
            if(top<150){
                var dif=1-top/150;
                $(".title").css({opacity:dif});
            }
        })
    });
```